# Approximation by mollifier in $\operatorname{Lip}_1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, optimal-transport

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact. I know that there exists $u\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ such that

$$\sup_{\phi \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)} \int_\Omega \phi \,d \mu = \int_\Omega u \,d\mu $$

I want to prove that $\int_\Omega u \, d\mu \leq C$ for a certain (prefixed) real constant $C.$

I was able to prove that for arbitrary $v\in C^1(\Omega)$ we have

$$\int_\Omega v \, d\mu \leq C $$ Now seems clear the result follows by approximation. Take a sequence $v_k \in C^1(\Omega)$ converging to $u$ in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$. In Santambrogio's book (Optimal Transport for applied mathematicians. pg 131) there's a hint to take $v_k = \eta_k\star u$

My problem: All the result I know for approximations via convolutions require $p<\infty$ and here I'm dealing exactly with $p=\infty$. Any ideas how this argument would work?

Comment: What is $\mu$? Since $\phi \mapsto \int_\Omega \phi \, \mathrm{d}\mu$ is linear and $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is a linear space, its supremum is either $0$ or $+\infty$.

Comment: $\mu$ can be taken as absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue. Also, the space $W^{1,\infty}$ coincides with the space of Lipschitz functions with Lipschitz constant equal to 1. I think this guarantees that the sup cannot be infinity.

Comment: No, $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ coincides with the space of Lipschitz function, but not necessarily with Lipschitz constant 1 (provide $\partial \Omega$ is $C^1$). Indeed, all constant functions are in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, so the supremum of your integral will be infinity. Are you sure you didn't mean $W^{1,\infty}_0(\Omega)$?